# Problem with passing value through Link, value is generated after clicking

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass value through pages in Link. However, the problem is, the value is generated after clicking. So the value I get in the next page is always null. Here is my code:

```
Go(){
  somefunction()
  .then(result => {this.setState({value: valueGeneratedBysomefunction})})
}

<Link to={{ pathname: '/nextpage', state: { value: this.state.value}}}>
  <Button size="sm" color="primary" onClick={this.Go.bind(this)}>Go!</Button>
</Link>
```

I then call the value in the next page by

```
console.log(props.location.state)
```

Result is:

```
value: ""
```

I am thinking, maybe I can redirect to another page programmatically and execute the redirect in `.then()`. However, I tried `history.push()`, `this.context.router.push()`. None of them works. My react-router version is ^3.2.0.

Comment: isn't your link winning here? The `onclick` might get hit, but I guess you get an error saying that you cannot set the state of an unmounted item?

Comment: @Icepickle yes you are absolutely right. I actually tried to remove Link and redirect to the page using a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever you want to do that should use the new `state` should be done in the `setState` callback because `setState` is asynchronous.

```js
Go() {
    somefunction()
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          value: valueGeneratedBysomefunction
        }, () => {
          // do the redirect here and you have access to the new state through this.state
          this.context.router.push({
            pathname: '/nextpage',
            state: { value: this.state.value }
          })
        })
      })
  }


<Button size="sm" color="primary" onClick={this.Go.bind(this)}>Go!</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to do the same thing, the thing is, I do not manage to redirect to another in function. :( Tried many solutions, but none of them works.

Comment: @ShaLi updated the code  with the actual redirecting. Try the code in the answer  and let me know if it works. Also for `this.context.router` to work you need to have wrapped your component with `withRouter`.

Comment: Acutally have tried it before and now again, error message is cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Comment: @ShaLi is your component wrapped with `withRouter` HOC ?

Comment: OMG I thought I did... `this.props.router.push` works. `this.context.router` somehow still does not work. But thank you so much for your help!